# CRM Dynamics Quick Create Form Label

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

I'm working with Quick Create Forms in Microsoft Dynamics CRM. Everything is working as expected. We have a sub-grid of one entity visible in it's related entity. When the User clicks on the + sign of that sub-grid, the Quick Create From appears exactly as it should.

The issue at hand though, is the physical form label of the Quick Create Form. For some reason the system keeps insisting on adding the words **Quick Create:** on the top of the form before the name of the entity (see image below).

Does anyone know how to prevent this from happening? This is a on-premise Dynamics CRM 365 environment.

**[image: strong text]**

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not customizable.

Maybe you can do some unsupported customizations like overwriting DOM objects, etc. But it’s not recommended.

[image]

Comment: How about localizable? We need to support multiple languages, but this text continues to appear in English regardless of what language we use. We have used various tools to make sure that all English text is captured and translated, but this stubbornly keeps showing up in English.

Comment: @Cailean oh thats really painful.. you can contact MS support for advise/workaround/fix..

Answer (score 0):

It appears to have something to do with a CRM Patch that we had installed to fix a Chrome CSS issue. That seems to have added something outside of our control. I'm not a fan of hacks/unsupported fixes, so I think we may have to talk to Microsoft about this one directly.